# Ruby on rails web app and api side by side issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, jwt

I'm new to Ruby on rails. I need to maintain a project which is a complete web app. Now I need to introduce APIs in it. I've searched and got many tutorials on API and web app separately. But didn't get any of them showing how these things will work together. I'm confused how that authentication will work for both.
Here is the application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  # before_filter :authenticate # HTTP AUTH DISABLED

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/403.html", :status => 403, :layout => false
    ## to avoid deprecation warnings with Rails 3.2.x (and incidentally using Ruby 1.9.3 hash syntax)
    ## this render call should be:
    # render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/403", formats: [:html], status: 403, layout: false
  end  

  def user_for_paper_trail
    if user_signed_in?
      current_user.full_name
    end
  end

  def info_for_paper_trail
    if user_signed_in?      
      { :user_id => current_user.id }
    end
  end    

  protected
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "admin" && password == "123"
    end
  end  

end
```

I need to know how to authenticate APIs? If I use JWT then how to override sign_in methods and do all that stuff separately for APIs and that also look overhead to me because authentication is already there.
Moreover it would be helpful if I get to know how to involve API functions in controller? Like I've user controller and all the methods for that for web app. Now I need the same methods for API. So I need to make new controller for API or that controller can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution worked for me is to use friendly token with devise_token_auth for api. And here is my before filter now:

```
before_filter do
if check_api_request
  authenticate_api_request
else
  authenticate_user!
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions here so I'll try to give a big picture answer:

In general, other controllers inherit from ApplicationController which (in your case) runs a before_filter. The filter can redirect or render and therefore prevent the execution of the specific route. Since all controllers inherit from ApplicationController, the filter is run before every action of your app (assuming the most common default case).

Presumably, API authentication is supposed to work in a different way than for the app's html frontend (perhaps an api key in a header). It looks like your app is using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. I'd have a look at it to see if you can just "switch on" a suitable authentication method for your API with it.

I hope this helps.